# How to create a webdav port for my application using Roxy?

Tags: marklogic, roxy

I want to create a local environment for a new application and wants to bootstrap it using Roxy. I have specified the various ports in my `local.properties` file.

```
app-port=6060
xcc-port=6070
webdav-port=6090
```

Upon hitting the bootstrap command `ml local bootstrap` my application is setup but I don't see a WEBDAV port created for my application. All other ports gets created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit `deploy/ml-config.xml`, and add a webdav-enabled http-server yourself. You should be able to use something like:

```
    <http-server>
      <http-server-name>${app-name}-webdav</http-server-name>
      <port>${webdav-port}</port>
      <webDAV>true</webDAV>
      <database name="${content-db}"/>
      <root>/</root>
      <authentication>${authentication-method}</authentication>
      <default-user name="${default-user}"/>
    </http-server>
```

You can use that next to the existing http-server in ml-config.xml..

HTH!

Comment: Wouldn't that create another http server?

Comment: Roxy will notice the webDAV flag, and create a webdav server out of this. This is also how MarkLogic stores it internally.